# Unexplained nightly system shutdown

Tags: shutdown

I recently took over a Dell XPS 9100, installed Ubuntu 12.04 via PXEboot.  I have done big builds and long over-the-net fetches with the machine.  In System Settings => Power, for `Suspend when inactive for`, I have `Don't suspend`.  I was planning to use this machine for overnight builds.

It has never crashed in my presence.  However, each morning, I discover the machine is off, not merely suspended.  I have not been able to find evidence of an automatic shutdown, but I may not be looking in the right places.

Running `last -f /var/log/wtmp`, I see entries like:

```
myuserid pts/2        :0               Thu Nov 21 18:37 - crash  (12:17).
```

But I think this just means I didn't log off.  Grepping thru `/var/log/*` only showed `shutdown` in this file.

How do I find the root cause of this automated shutdown or crash?

Comment: Any entries like this: "thermal_sys: Critical temperature reached(87 C),shutting down"?